# Change transitions page duration

Tags: windows-phone-7, silverlight-toolkit, transition

I'm using Windows phone Silverlight Toolkit transitions with this XAML code:

```xml
<toolkit:TransitionService.NavigationInTransition>
    <toolkit:NavigationInTransition>
        <toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Backward>
            <toolkit:SwivelTransition Mode="BackwardIn"/>
        </toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Backward>
        <toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Forward>
            <toolkit:SwivelTransition Mode="ForwardIn"/>
        </toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Forward>
    </toolkit:NavigationInTransition>
</toolkit:TransitionService.NavigationInTransition>
<toolkit:TransitionService.NavigationOutTransition>
    <toolkit:NavigationOutTransition>
        <toolkit:NavigationOutTransition.Backward>
            <toolkit:SwivelTransition Mode="BackwardOut"/>
        </toolkit:NavigationOutTransition.Backward>
        <toolkit:NavigationOutTransition.Forward>
            <toolkit:SwivelTransition Mode="ForwardOut"/>
        </toolkit:NavigationOutTransition.Forward>
    </toolkit:NavigationOutTransition>
</toolkit:TransitionService.NavigationOutTransition>
```

Is there any way to change transition animation duration?

Comment: You could probably just open up the toolkit and edit it yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no exposed property for this. If you want to change it you'll have to edit the source yourself.

**However**, the animations in the toolkit were created to mimic the native behaviour of the OS. If you change this you risk creating something which could seem out of place as it's not quite right. The so-called "uncanney valley".